# How do you implement auto incremented sequence values in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-xe

In a Oracle database table, how are auto incremented sequence values done with PL/SQL such as for a key value or id typed columns?

Included is a discussion on sizing table resources based on what you know about the projected growth of all the related tables in a given schema.  How many piano tuners are there in the city of Chicago?  Probably less than the population of the city altogether... :) and so on.

```
Know your data.
```

How do I do that?  Read on.

Comment: Is it a tutorial on sequence ?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the comment.  I put the abstract up top.  The tutorial just adds a little context to the idea.  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Database Triggers to Auto Increment Column Values

One possible approach is to use **database triggers**.  The values are ensured unique through the implementation of *sequence typed database objects*.

[image: Creating Sequences for Individual Table ID Values]

In the example above, the table `FUNDRAISER` has an associated sequence called `FUNDRAISER_SEQ` for a primary key value.

[image: Trigger design for auto sequences]

### The Parts List:  What you need for the example.

```
CREATE TABLE  "FUND_PEOPLE" 
   (    "PERSON_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "ANONYMOUS_IND" VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "ALIAS_IND" VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "ALIAS_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
        "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
        "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(50), 
        "PHONE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(20), 
        "EMAIL_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(100), 

     CONSTRAINT "FUND_PEOPLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PERSON_ID") ENABLE
   ) ;
```

This is an older sample of code, but it the

```
SELECT FROM ... INTO DUAL
```

Construct was what we did with older releases of the Oracle Database.  Release 11g changes that so that sequence increments can be assigned directly to a PL/SQL variable or a SQL statement call.  Both will work.

Challenge yourself to figure out what the revised PL/SQL might look like...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_FUND_PEOPLE" 
  before insert on "FUND_PEOPLE"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."PERSON_ID" is null then 
    :NEW."PERSON_ID" := "FUND_PEOPLE_SEQ".nextval; 
  end if; 
end;
```

The notation is:

1. "BI" for Before INSERT
2. :NEW for the value of the column value after the event.

[image: Table structure before record insert]

`FUND_ID` is the column that is ignored in the insert statement.  The starting value of each sequence is *20*.  A call to the `SEQ.NEXTVAL` value increments the sequence by the amount identified in the sequence declaration.

[image: Record insert results with the trigger enabled]

### A Brief Discussion on Sequence Sizing

If you spec a sequence **without a MAXIMUM value**, the system assigns the largest possible integer handled by the database, which is 20+ digits long.

> Now what are we going to do with a table that contains records
>   numbering twenty or more orders of magnitude:
>   `"9999999999999999999999999999"`?
>
> **Hmmmm...**  I've heard of "defensiveness in coding", but for most applications, this is... in defensible?

Consider looking at the original project design I have worked with on Google Code:
[Google Code Project: Fundraiser Organizer](https://code.google.com/p/fundraiser-event-organizer/)

[image: Fund Raiser's Report]

> This is the rough relation in record counts between each entity in the
>   schema I set up.  The two circles are metrics which are proportional
>   to what values they calculate or aggregate.  Considering the data 
>   cases, what are the relative magnitudes for each count of records?

A look at the [first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfxgH.png) shows my estimates.  This project started out as a sheet of data to keep track of an fund raising drive.  Hope you find it informative and thought inspiring!

The UI and my testing efforts were conducted on a public demo site hosted by Oracle at [Oracle Apex Demo System](http://APEX.ORACLE.COM)